# Unable to exclude dependency from a jar

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

Unable to exclude dependency from a jar, how should I go about doing this.

```
compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.+') {
    exclude module: 'aws-java-sdk-machinelearning'
}
```

gradle dependencies still shows this as well and the above exclude always get downloaded as well.

Comment: use both group name and module name with exclude.

Comment: Your example works fine for me. I don't get `machinelearning` dependencies. And when I remove that line, then it appears. Gradle version 2.13

Answer (score 1):

I have similar situation but i did like below .if it helps .. please select as answered.

```
  dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.net.foragerr.jmeter:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.0.5-2.13"
    classpath "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.3"
    classpath(group: 'kg.apc', name: 'jmeter-plugins-extras-libs', version: '1.3.1') {
        exclude group: 'commons-math3', module: 'commons-math3'
        exclude group: 'commons-pool2', module: 'commons-pool2'
    }

  }
}
```